# Push Contact form 7 variable to front end after submission

Tags: plugins, php, api, front-end, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a contact form 7 form that's sending information to an API. I want to display the API response on the front end.

I record the user information, then post it using wp_remote_post, with my example url. I want to be able to show the API response / $body on the front end. I have set it up to capture it in the debug log, but want to know if there is a way to post it to the frontend where my form is.

Normal Var Dump and print_r do not work as contact form 7 is an Ajax function.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','Kiri_cf7_api_sender');

 function Kiri_cf7_api_sender ( $contact_form) {
     
    
    
     
     if ( $contact_form->title === 'Quote_form')
     {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ($submission) 
        {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
            
            
            $name = $posted_data["your-name"];
            $surname = $posted_data["your-name2"];
            $phone = $posted_data["tel-922"];
            
            
            //example url//
            $url = www.mytestapi.com?$name&$surname&$phone;
            
            
            
            
            $response = wp_remote_post ($url);
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
            
            
            
            

             
            
            
            
                     ob_start();                     // start buffer capture

    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($surname);
    var_dump($phone);
    
    
    
    
    

    $contents = ob_get_contents();  // put the buffer into a variable
    ob_end_clean();                 // end capture
    error_log($contents); 
            
             

            
            


        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a contact form 7 form that's sending information to an API. I want to display the API response on the front end.

there are 2 ways to go about solving this type of problem,

1- Use the CF7 plugin's message response hook,

```
add_filter('wpcf7_display_message', 'my_response_msg',10,2);
function my_response_msg($message, $status){
    if('mail_sent_ok'==$status){
      $form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form(); //in case you need the cf7 form object to validate....
      $message = 'Api response is: '. $api;
    }
  return $message;
}
```

however, keep in mind that you can only use text in this message, HTML markup will not work due to the limitations of the CF7 plugin reported [here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/issues/345) and [here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/issues/396), and as you can appreciate, the functionality did exist, but the plugin author tends to bury his head in the sand on such type of issues.

2- if you need a richer interface, then you can either redirect the form submission process to another page on which you display your API response by storing it in a transient using similar logic to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817819/how-to-access-contact-form-7-submitted-data-on-a-redirect-page/60836760#60836760)...

or you can load a custom JavaScript  on the form page which you trigger on the CF7 successful submission `wpcf7mailsent` [event](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) and then fetch the API request stored as a transient on the server using an AJAX request.